# How do I get data from a Flux in an AbstractGatewayFilterFactory

Tags: java, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a `ReactiveDiscoveryClient` that provides a method `Flux<ServiceInstance> getInstances(String serviceId)`.  I want to use the result of that method in my GatewayFilterFactory's apply method.  However,

```
ServiceInstance si = reactiveDiscoveryClient.getInstances(config.getServiceId()).block();
```

fails because the block operations are not allowed.  Is there anyway around it?

What I've done is cheat since my ReactiveDiscoveryClient has an in-memory map that contains the services and I just provide an extra method that gets the value I need.

Answer (score 1):

That's rare, as by default, those actions are allowed. From the [**Spring Cloud Documentation:**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html)

> **[***27.1. @EnableDiscoveryClient***](http://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#discovery-client)**
>
> Spring Cloud Commons provides the  @EnableDiscoveryClient annotation. This looks for
> implementations of the DiscoveryClient and ReactiveDiscoveryClient
> interfaces with META-INF/spring.factories. Implementations of the
> discovery client add a configuration class to spring.factories under
> the org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient
> key. Examples of DiscoveryClient implementations include Spring Cloud
> Netflix Eureka, Spring Cloud Consul Discovery, and Spring Cloud
> Zookeeper Discovery.
>
> **Spring Cloud will provide both the blocking and reactive service
> discovery clients by default**. You can disable the blocking and/or
> reactive clients easily by setting
> spring.cloud.discovery.blocking.enabled=false or
> spring.cloud.discovery.reactive.enabled=false. To completely disable
> service discovery you just need to set
> spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=false.

---

At least for what it's told in the last paragraph, you should be able to perform a `block()`. Anyway, you could try by setting these params, as should be enough to be allowed to invoke it:

```
spring.cloud.discovery.blocking.enabled=true
spring.cloud.discovery.reactive.enabled=true
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true
```

---

Also, not sure if related, but note this warning as well (just in case)

[image]

Comment: I actually opened up a bug on that screenshot you posted https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/2148 the reason I was using ReactiveDiscoveryClient was because the DiscoveryClient didn't work based on the instructions that was given.

Comment: *those spring guys...*

Comment: In the end I reverted back to my older branch which used an older version of Gateway because of https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1815 which should be resolved in 2020.0.2 if we're lucky.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano you should make that an answer, you fixed it so...it would be the right thing ; )

Comment: Well he's already apologizing for this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCRnSmw83Vg